Listing people - option to create new person - afform
I have a formbuilder question.
In webform, when you have a select list of existing contacts, there are two options that are super helpful:

The ability to select the fields that are displayed in the select list.  So I can have everyone displayed as "Last, First (City)" for example.
The ability to allow creation of a new person right in the select list.  There is an option that shows up called "+ Create New +".

Are these possible with formbuilder?  I have tried and maybe I'm blind but I just don't see them.
Thank you!
